# css in working in FF and chrome but not loading in IE 8

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using this path of css in my aspx pages:

```
<link href="Styles/960.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It is working fine in FF and chrome but in IE 8, css is not loaded.

I try using localhost:9133/styles/style.css in IE and css is loaded/opened.

```
:focus {/* remember to define focus styles! */
    outline: 0;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table {/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
a img {
    border: 0;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "homenaje";
    src: url('fonts/Homenaje-Regular.ttf') ;
}
```

Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: it is on my local computer @suresh.g

Comment: How do you know it doesn't get loaded in IE?

Comment: because there is not styling applied on page elements @FyodorSoikin

Comment: Can you look at IE's developer's console and see if there are any errors?

Comment: Use the developer tools to see what is going on in background.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: in IE dev tools (F12), when you go to the css tab are the files showing up at all? are you using css elements that aren't supported by IE? are the element style attributes not getting overriden (check Trace Styles) by something else?

Comment: Just because no styling is applied on IE8 doesn't mean the stylesheet isn't being loaded. Are you sure the styles you expect to see are supported by IE8?

Comment: @Veli : I am not sure. I have updated question with some css. Is it not supported in IE ?

Comment: @EdSF , updated question with some css. Is it not supported in IE ?

Comment: I don't know about the rest of the styles, but your `@font-face` code isn't going to work in IE6-8, they require `.eot` font files.

Answer (score 0):

In order for selectors to work in IE8, you need to specify [doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp):

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Ok i've got one more idea - is IE showing the page in compatibility mode?